# Receive a time stamp from input in a shell script

Tags: linux, bash, date

I am working on a script that receives two inputs:

1. timeZone (America/Los_Angeles)
2. a time stamp in UTC with the following format `"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ”`)

The script is supposed to find the offset and add it to the input timestamp, so when I run:

```
./TZ-converst.sh Asia/Kolkata 2016-12-07t00-00-00z
```

the output will be `2016-12-07t00-05-30z`.

The offset for each timezone comes easily:

```
offset="$(TZ=":$tz" date +%z )"
```

However, I am having a hard time adding this offset to the input time `"2016-12-07t00-00-00z"`.

I am trying to use `date -d` to use the input parameter but I keep getting

> "usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...[-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]"

Any thoughts?

Comment: `date -d '2016-12-07T00:00:00Z +1 hour'` yields `Wed Dec  7 01:00:00 UTC 2016`

Comment: no it does not . this is what I get after running thatcommand "usage: date [-jnu] [-d dst] [-r seconds] [-t west] [-v[+|-]val[ymwdHMS]] ...
            [-f fmt date | [[[mm]dd]HH]MM[[cc]yy][.ss]] [+format]"

Comment: To be honest , just an exact copy paste of @bishop date -d command, in my machine yields `Wed Dec  7 03:00:00 EET 2016` . What is your `date --version`? My debi has GNU date version 8.26

Comment: date --version is 8.4

Comment: @Erin According to this post, it seems that you are trying to do things with date that your version doesn't support. http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166856/why-cant-my-date-deal-with-timezones

Comment: @Erin reading this post, it seem your enter a minus `-` as separator between hour, minutes and seconds, instead of colon `:`... On my system, `LANG=C TZ=Asia/Kolkata date -d '2016-12-07t00:00:00z'` return: `Wed Dec  7 05:30:00 IST 2016`

Answer (score 1):

Print *Time Zone Offset*, according to summer time derivation, at a specific time:

```
TZ=Asia/Kolkata date -d '2016-12-07t00:00:00z' +%z
+0530
```

Care to keep syntax:

> *Year* <kbd>-</kbd> *Month* <kbd>-</kbd> *Day* <kbd>t</kbd> *Hours* <kbd>:</kbd> *Minutes* <kbd>:</kbd> *Seconds*  <kbd>z</kbd>